# How do I remove part of a string in an excel cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a long list of names (strings) that have extra information in them I don't want in the cell but the extra information is not standard.

How can I remove the extra strings info from these strings?

For example these are a sample of the strings I'm working with:

- Hill, Jeremy CIN RB
- Brown, Jaron ARI WR (I)
- Robinson, Denard JAC RB (O)
- Robinson, Denard JAC RB (Q)
- Dixon, Kenneth BAL RB (R)
- Janovich, Andy DEN RB (R) (I)
- Janovich, Andy DEN RB (R) (O)
- Lasco, Daniel NOS RB (R) (Q)

and I want them all to be just **"Last name, First name"**

If I use `=LEFT(A20,LEN(A20)-7)` I won't always get all the extra string, what other formulas can I use?

Cheers!

Comment: do you want to ignore everything after RB or "(". try to use FIND to get the index of this string (RB of "(" ) and get left upto this index -1

Comment: Or you want to keep only one word after the "," ?

Answer (score 3):

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1)-1)
```

Try this formula. this formula finds the position of second space in the string and get everything left of it

[image]